# Symplectomorphism Preserves Cotangent fibrations

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold with local coordinates $x^1,\dots,x^n$ and $T^\ast M$ the cotangent bundle with induced coordinates $x^1,\dots,x^n,\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$ . Let $\alpha$ be the tautological one form on $T^\ast M$. That is, $\alpha\in \Gamma(T(T^\ast M))$ where $\alpha=\xi_idx^i$. Let $\omega=-d\alpha=dx^i\wedge d\xi_i$. We have that $(T^\ast M,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold. Let $g:T^\ast M\to T^\ast M$ be a symplectomorphism that preserves $\alpha$ (i.e. $g^\ast\alpha=\alpha$).

I'm trying to show that if for some $(p,\sigma_p)\in T^\ast_p M$ we have $g(p,\sigma_p)=(q,\eta_q)$, then $g(T^\ast_p M)=T^\ast_q M$.

So far this is what I have:

Let $V\in\Gamma(T(T^\ast M))$ be the symplectic dual of $\alpha$. That is, $\omega(V,\cdot)=\alpha$. Let $\theta$ denote the flow of $V$. I can show that $g\circ\theta_t=\theta_t\circ g$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ or equivalently, that $g_\ast V=V$. I can show that each $\theta_t$ preserves $T_p^\ast M$ for arbitrary $p\in M$. That is, I can show that $\theta_t(T^\ast_p M)=T^\ast_p M$. This follows from actually computing the flow, which turns out to be $\theta_t(p,\mu_p)=(p,e^t\mu_p)$. How do I use these facts to show what I wrote above? Am I missing something obvious? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone cares, this question was answered here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/175807/lifting-a-diffeomorphism-to-the-cotangent-bundle

Comment: I noticed this question and I was going to answer (and I noticed your two questions on mathoverflow). I think essentially the key points are: (a) $g$ commutes with $\theta$ so $g(p,\sigma_p)=(q,\eta_q)$ $\implies$ $g(p,\lambda\sigma_p) = (q,\lambda\eta_q)$ for *positive* $\lambda>0$ and (b) by the differentiability of $g$ at $(p,0)$, you can conclude that $g(p,\lambda\sigma_p)=(q,\lambda\eta_q)$ *for all* $\lambda$. I find (b) unnecessary though (I think the hint in da Silva's textbook is misleading in this regard?) ...

Comment: ... If you know (b) is true for $\lambda=0$ (which you observed is a continuity argument), then you can conclude that $g(p,\sigma_p)=(q,\eta_q)$ $\implies$ $g(p,0)=(q,0)$, and since this is true for all $\sigma_p\in T_p^{\ast} M$, it follows that $g$ is fiber-preserving (i.e., $g(T_p^{\ast} M)=T_q^{\ast}M$). I guess this is essentially what Robert Bryant stated in his answer, but this is the way I thought about (and expressed) the solution. (Also, the linearity of $g$ on fibers follows once you've proven that $g=f^{\#}$ so this also proves (b).) Hope it isn't redundant and helps in some way!

Comment: BTW, the fact that (b) is true for $\lambda=0$ can be seen as follows (without a continuity argument): if $g(p,\sigma_p)=(q,\eta_q)$, then we wish to show that $g(p,0)=(q,0)$. Indeed, if $g(p,0)=(q,\eta_q')$, then applying (a) yields $g(p,0)=(q,\lambda\eta_q')$ *for all positive* $\lambda>0$. However, this forces $\eta_q'=0$ (just apply the claim of the last sentence for two different (positive) values of $\lambda$).

Comment: This is useful, thanks for your comments. I do agree that the hint in Da Silva's book was a little confusing, I don't get why it holds for all $\lambda<0$ (without proving the claim)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @user54440. You can prove $g(p,\sigma_p)=(q,\eta_q)$ $\implies$ $g(p,\lambda\sigma_p)=(q,\lambda\eta_q)$ for all negative $\lambda < 0$ as follows: assume $g(p,-\sigma_p)=(q,\eta_q')$, in which case the claim for $\lambda>0$ implies $g(p,\lambda\sigma_p)=(q,\lambda\eta_q')$ for negative $\lambda<0$. However, $g$ is differentiable at $(p,0)$, and thus $\lambda\to g(p,\lambda\sigma_p)$ is differentiable at $\lambda=0$ (by the chain rule). Now, compare the left-hand and right-hand derivatives of this function at $\lambda=0$ to deduce that $\eta_p'=-\eta_p$. QED

Comment: Oh nice, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to take this off the unanswered list, the answer to this question was provided here

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175807/lifting-a-diffeomorphism-to-the-cotangent-bundle